# SharePoint 2013: What is the fastest way to retrieve all files and folders in a library with many items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

At first I used [GetItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListGetItems), but retrieving 5000 items was really slow even for indexed views. (around 2 minutes)

Now I came back to use what I know retrieves them really fast (less then 10 seconds) - [GetListItemChangesSinceToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListGetListItemChangesSinceToken).

The problem with this endpoint is that the results are fetched in XML and missing some details and that overall it is supposed to be used for changes and not just retrieving Items.

Comment: Have you tried `Rest Api`

Comment: Yes, I've edited the links to be more accurate. Both of them are performed using REST.